# How to fetch the HTML DOM content of an authorized page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mshtml

I have Windows Forms app where I am loading a site. I login to the site inside Windows Forms with valid credentials.

Then somehow I manage to get valid session id & this is how URL looks like after the valid credentials

```
var url = "http://www.somewebsite123.com/portal/sessionId=123";
```

I am using `Microsoft.mshtml` & `AxInterop.ShDocVw` for fetching the content of the authorized page.

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    using (Stream data = client.OpenRead(new Uri(url)))
    {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
      string htmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But at the below line, it throwing the error

```
strHTML = ((IHTMLElement)htmlContent.document).innerHTML.ToString();
```

Error

```
    Internal error (WWC-00006)
    An unexpected error occurred: ORA-01403: no data found (WWV-16016)
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: ORA-01403 error is happening in server, Oracle query error? Are you able to debug the root cause?

Comment: @RistoM, I don't have access to that DB. somewebsite123.com is a site which I don't own

Answer (score 1):

The actual DOM content can be found in `WebException.Response` when WebClient hits 4XX or 5XX:

```
try {
     // Webclient that raise 4XX
}
catch (WebException webex) 
{
   using (var streamReader = new new StreamReader(webex.Response.GetResponseStream())) { 
    var domContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   } 
}
```